# A question about AdaptiveMonteCarlo method in NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, random

I’m currently getting to grips with the `AdaptiveMonteCarlo` method in the `NIntegrate` function. I’ve been using the sub-method `MonteCarloRule`, however I’m unsure from reading the Mathematica documentation exactly how the option `Points` (for this sub-method) actually works. Suppose for example I have the following integral $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x)dx $$ Then using `NIntegrate` I have

```
NIntegrate[Sin[x], {x,0,Pi}, Method->{“AdaptiveMonteCarlo”, Method->{“MonteCarloRule”, “Points”->5}, “MaxRecursion”->200}, AccuracyGoal->5, PrecisionGoal->5]
```

Now, I realise that I could simply use `Integrate` on this integral and get an exact result, but I wanted to choose a relatively simple analytic integral as practise.

Using `Points->5` gives a pretty accurate result, but does specifying `Points->5` mean that `NIntegrate` only uses 5 points in its Monte Carlo routine? I’m assuming there must be more to it than that otherwise I wouldn’t expect the result to be so close to the true result.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108156/34008) to a similar question ["Monte Carlo integration with random numbers generated from a Gaussian distribution"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45133/34008).

Comment: @AntonAntonov  Thanks for the link. I’ve had a read through your answer, but I’m still unsure as to what `Points` does?! Is it related to `PointGenerator`?

Comment: `Points` specifies the number of sampling points in a single rule application. The point generator uses that option value.

Comment: @AntonAntonov  So is the example I gave literally only using 5 sample points to calculate the integral?