# Number of realizations in NExpectation, Method Monte Carlo

Tags: numerical-integration, random, simulation

I have been looking in [`NExpectation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NExpectation.html) about how large the sample size is when *Mathematica* performs Monte Carlo simulation. For example, if we write

```
NExpectation[x Sin[x] + 1, x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], Method -> "MonteCarlo"]
```

which is the number of realizations of $x$ that Mathematica makes?

Also, I do not understand well how you can specify the number of realizations you want. For instance, if I want $1000$ realizations of $x$, what should I write?

Comment: If you have looked at the documentation, you already know that `NExpectation` does integration of `expression` if the distribution is continuous, or discrete sum if this is a discrete one. In your case, it will do integration of $(x \sin(x)+1)$ with the `NormalDistribution`

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas But Monte Carlo is based on sampling: [http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MonteCarloIntegration.html](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MonteCarloIntegration.html). I would like to know which $N$ Mathematica takes.

Comment: maybe you will be interested in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45133/monte-carlo-integration-with-random-numbers-generated-from-a-gaussian-distributi?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

The number of samples taken by the `"MonteCarlo"` `Method` of `NExpectation[]` is controlled through an *undocumented* option. To see what happens, let's use a function with `Sow[]`:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := (Sow[x]; x Sin[x] + 1)
```

and then evaluate

```
tst = Reap[NExpectation[f[x], x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], 
                        Method -> "MonteCarlo"]];
```

We then find that

```
Length[tst[[-1, 1]]]
   1012001
```

Now, let's adjust that *undocumented* option to use $10^7$ samples:

```
tst2 = Reap[NExpectation[f[x], x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], 
                         Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "SamplingIncrement" -> 1*^7}]];
```

and we find that

```
Length[tst2[[-1, 1]]]
   10012001
```

so, $10^7$ samples plus a little extra was used.

To see all the other adjustable options:

```
 Options[Statistics`Library`NExpectationMonteCarloMethod]
   {PrecisionGoal -> 2, AccuracyGoal -> 3, MaxIterations -> 50000, 
    "RandomSeed" -> Automatic, EvaluationMonitor -> None, 
    ConfidenceLevel -> 19/20, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, 
    "ReportingMethod" -> Automatic, "SamplingIncrement" -> 1000000}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NIntegrate` and specify for the method "MonteCarlo" the maximum number of points:

```
NIntegrate[(x*Sin[x] + 1) PDF[NormalDistribution[], 
   x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> 999}]

(* 1.63975 *)
```

This shows that 1000 points were used:

```
res =
  Reap@NIntegrate[(x*Sin[x] + 1) PDF[NormalDistribution[], 
      x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
    Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "MaxPoints" -> 999}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x]];
Length@res[[2, 1]]

(* 1000 *)
```

Also, you might want to take a look into [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108156/34008) of ["Monte Carlo integration with random numbers generated from a Gaussian distribution"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45133/34008).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at official doc and NExpectation options:

```
Options[NExpectation]

{AccuracyGoal -> \[Infinity], Compiled -> Automatic, 
 Method -> Automatic, PrecisionGoal -> Automatic, 
 WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision, TargetUnits -> Automatic}
```

it is true that we do not find how to have a fine control (number of realizations etc.).

Concerning the number of realizations, here 100, you can use this trick:

```
NExpectation[Block[{$IterationLimit = 100}, x*Sin[x] + 1], 
 x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], Method -> "MonteCarlo"]
```

> 1.60641

to be compared with the more accurate result:

> 1.60624

Comment: Since `NExpectation` does not hold its arguments, `Block[{$IterationLimit = 100}, x*Sin[x] + 1]` evaluates to `x*Sin[x] + 1` before it is passed to `NExpectation`, and the change to `$IterationLimit` is lost before it can have any effect. (I don't think `$IterationLimit` works in the way implied here. I'd be surprised if it is used in any other way than what is described in [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ControllingInfiniteEvaluation.html).)