# How to calculate this integral with highly oscillating integrand?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I mean
$$\int_ 0^{2\pi}\frac {\sin (10050 t)\sin (10251 t)\cos (2022 t)} 
{\sin (50 t)\sin (51 t)} dt.$$

Here is my unsuccessful trial:

```
NIntegrate[Cos[2022*t]*Sin[10050*t]*Sin[10251*t]/Sin[50*t]/Sin[51*t], {t, 0,2*Pi}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5]
```

> NIntegrate::ncvb :
> NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 
> recursive bisections in t near {t} = {3.15386} .
> NIntegrate obtained 11.171230707439639 and 8.934855726568145 for
> the integral and error estimates .

I don't find an answer in [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#775797877) (see the "Finite Region Oscillatory Integration" section).

Comment: Try TrigReduce on the integrand

Comment: I am interested rather in its numeric calculation (The documentation presents examples of such type.).

Comment: Maybe `MinRecursion -> 8, Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 21}`.

Comment: @Goofy: Many thanks from me to you. This is it. Can you present your comment as an answer, elaborating it? In particular, how did you come to these options?

Comment: It should be noticed that `NIntegrate[
 Cos[2022*t]*Sin[10050*t]*Sin[10251*t]/Sin[50*t]/Sin[51*t], {t, 0, 
  2*Pi}, Method -> {"LevinRule", "Kernel" -> Cos[2022*t]}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 8]` results in `8.75152` which is far away from the right one.

Comment: As it is shown in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/274058) using brute force with `NIntegrate` works. I.e. no symbolic processing, no singularity handler, large min & max recursions. (Also, `NDSolve` , shmendy-solve.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a fast way:

```
NIntegrate[
  Cos[2022*t]*Sin[10050*t]*Sin[10251*t]/Sin[50*t]/Sin[51*t], {t, 0, 
   2*Pi}, MinRecursion -> 8, 
  Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 21}] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.224591, 18.849555920879993`}*)
```

The integrand is analytic and the Gauss rule converges fast on analytic functions, so a high-order rule is probably going to be helpful. There are about 44K zeros. The Gauss-Kronrod rule is order `3*21+2` and the interval is divided into `2^8` subintervals. Together that's `2^8*65` or almost 17K zeros.
Since the result is `5.999999999790308 * Pi`, something must be working well. It seems like undersampling, but aliasing is a possible explanation for the unexpected accuracy (which I cannot explain).

```
SolveValues[
  Cos[2022*t]*Sin[10050*t]*Sin[10251*t] == 0 && 0 <= t <= 2*Pi, 
  t] // Length

(*44245*)

NIntegrate[Cos[2022*t]*Sin[10050*t]*Sin[10251*t]/Sin[50*t]/Sin[51*t],
  Evaluate@Flatten@{t, 
     SolveValues[
      Cos[2022*t]*Sin[10050*t]*Sin[10251*t] == 0 && 0 <= t <= 2*Pi, 
      t]}, MinRecursion -> 0, 
  Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{19.1047, 18.849555921538766`}*)
```

The result is `6.000000000000003 * Pi`, which is more accurate but takes much longer.

Comment: +1. I accept your answer, but others also are good and deep.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if this would be as effective if the big peak was at unknown location, rather than at the start and end.

Comment: Perhaps you saw my answer where I used `Reduce` to find the zeroes. I did not check if some of the other solutions from the output of `Reduce` that had auxiliary constants were distinct zeroes from the ones I used. I corrected my answer and checked that we found the same zeroes after using sort. Reduce is about 7 times faster for finding the zeroes but tedious to use to obtain numerical values.

Comment: In my new answer I also checked that using Gauss-Legendre points directly without the overhead of NIntegrate in each sub-interval defined by the zeroes has similar speed to the answer you provided.

Comment: @mikado there is a peak in the middle but `Plot` misses it if the number of points is not increased from the default choice. For example `Plot[Cos[2022*t]*Sin[10050*t]*Sin[10251*t]/Sin[50*t]/Sin[51*t], {t, 0,
   2*Pi}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 4000]`.

Comment: @mikado changing the upper bound to  `RandomReal[{1, 4}]*Pi/2` , `MinRecursion` to 10 and `MaxRecursion` to 20 (for example), using `Do`, after evaluating the integral 100 times, I found an average of 0.1 seconds per integral with no error using the method above.

Comment: @mikado This puts the peak in a random place and there seems no change in behavior: `offset = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}]
NIntegrate[Cos[2022*t]*Sin[10050*t]*Sin[10251*t]/Sin[50*t]/Sin[51*t], {t, 0 + offset, 2*Pi + offset}, MinRecursion -> 8, Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 21}] // AbsoluteTiming` -- as I mentioned, my guess is that the feature here is aliasing (integrating the major components of some spectral decomposition), not sampling, accidentally or otherwise, the major intervals of support or peaks. But I can't prove it.

Answer (score 7):

*Note: As OP has pointed out in a comment, a similar calculation is available [here on Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4508185).*

OPs integral can be written as
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} f(50t) f(51t) \cos(2022 t) dt
$$
with the auxiliary function

```
f[x_] := Sin[201*x]/Sin[x];
```

The division can be carried out explicitly, because
`(X^201-Y^201)/(X-Y)` is a polynomial. The answer is
$$
f(x) = e^{-200 ix} + e^{-198 ix} +  \ldots + e^{-2ix} + 1 + e^{2ix} + \ldots + e^{198 ix} + e^{200 ix}
$$
or as Mathematica code:

```
falternative[x_]:=Sum[Exp[I*k*x],{k,-200,200,2}];
```

To check this, use

```
f[x]-falternative[x]//FullSimplify
(* 0 *)
```

OPs integrand is therefore

```
integrand = falternative[50*t]*falternative[51*t]*Cos[2022*t]//TrigToExp//Expand;
```

This returns a linear combination of terms of the form $e^{i \omega t}$ with integer $\omega$, and the coefficient of $\omega = 0$ is $3$, therefore the value of the integral is
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} f(50t) f(51t) \cos(2022 t) dt
= 6\pi
$$

Comment: +1. Thank you for your work. I knew the exact answer from https : // math . stacketchange . com/questions/4508185/evaluate - int2 - pi - 0 - frac - cos2022t - sin10050t - sin10251t - sin50t - sin #4508185 and that was a reason to ask it. I am interested rather in its numeric calculation (The documentation presents examples of such type.).

Comment: Really interesting question and answer.  EE's sometimes call sin(x)/x the "sync" functions, and there are variants based on pi, etc.

Answer (score 4):

With patience, Monte Carlo methods can be effective

```
NIntegrate[
 Cos[2022*t]*Sin[10050*t]*Sin[10251*t]/Sin[50*t]/Sin[51*t], {t, 0, 
  2*Pi}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5, MaxRecursion -> 10^6, 
 MaxPoints -> 10^8, Method -> "AdaptiveQuasiMonteCarlo"]
(* 18.8496 *)

% - 6 π
(* 2.4873*10^-8 *)
```

Comment: This is good, but there is no need for Monte-Carlo -- just use "GlobalAdaptive" without symbolic pre-processing and without singularity handling.

Comment: +1. Unexpected accuracy of Monte-Carlo method.

Comment: @AntonAntonov there are reasons not to use Monte Carlo as the last method you try for a difficult integral, but it is often a very good first choice.

Comment: I have never heard that rule of thumb for 1D integrals. :) (Only for dimensions larger than, say, 5...)

Comment: A few questions: **1.** Do you have experience in using Monte-Carlo integration algorithms in non-WL systems? **2.** If yes, have you seen other adaptive Monte-Carlo algorithms? **3.** Have you used -- and interested in -- importance sampling integration algorithms?

Comment: @AntonAntonov in principle, I am interested in those things.  A major interest is in estimating the effectiveness of electronic systems (and optimising their design).  In practice, average performance might be interesting (and computed by an integral).  In practice, focusing on worst case behaviour avoids the need to make lots of questionable judgements about relative probability of various conditions.

Comment: This discussion is interesting. I admit that I always ignored MonteCarlo as I never had to work high dimensional integrals or complicated geometries but indeed as the error term depends on a crude measure of the function, MonteCarlo seems like the most reliable choice. It would be interesting to use Importance Sampling weighted by the amplitude of the function. Perhaps using the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45133/monte-carlo-integration-with-random-numbers-generated-from-a-gaussian-distributi)

Comment: or including a [custom rule](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118324/how-to-implement-custom-integration-rules-for-use-by-nintegrate) for NIntegrate.

Answer (score 4):

The issue with this integrand seems to be the highly oscillatory nature which makes it difficult to find the right step spacing. In the following I will give **two methods** to deal with the small step sizes.

The integrand:

```
g[t_] = Cos[2022*t]*Sin[10050*t]*Sin[10251*t]/Sin[50*t]/Sin[51*t]
```

#### First method: integration using NDSolve

One possibility is to use the adaptive methods of `NDSolve` to find the right step sizes:

**Edit**: As recommended in the comments, I changed the starting point from 10^(-12) to `$MachineEpsilon/2`

```
AbsoluteTiming[
NDSolveValue[{v'[t] == g[t], v[$MachineEpsilon/2] == 0}, 
v[2 Pi], {t, $MachineEpsilon/2, 2 Pi}]/(6*Pi) - 1]
```

output: `(*{0.391597, -2.92904*10^-6}*)`

If we need more precision we can adjust the options of `NDSolve`, for example :

```
AbsoluteTiming[
NDSolveValue[{v'[t] == g[t], v[$MachineEpsilon/2] == 0}, 
v[2 Pi], {t, $MachineEpsilon/2, 2 Pi}, PrecisionGoal -> 10, 
AccuracyGoal -> 10, Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"]/(6*Pi) - 1] (* relative error *)
```

output: `(*{0.438849, 1.79297*10^-10}*)`

#### Second method: summing over sub-intervals specified by the zeroes of the function.

A more manual approach is to consider a partition of the interval defined by the zeroes of the function.
Specifically, for `x[r]` the r'th zero of the integrand, we consider the following partition of the original interval `Interval[0,2*Pi]=IntervalUnion[Interval[x[0],x[1]],Interval[x[1],x[2]],....]` (this is just a representation not part of the code)

**Find the zeroes:**

Using `Solve` or `SolveValues` takes a lot of time. As such, Reduce is used instead as it is roughly seven times faster in this case :

```
a = Reduce[Cos[2022*t]*Sin[10050*t]*Sin[10251*t] == 0 && 0 <= t <= 2*Pi, t];
```

However, the output format is a mixture of equalities and inequalities for auxiliary constants. The code below extracts and constructs numerical zeroes from the output of `Reduce`:

```
zeroes = (List @@ a[[;; -5, 2]])~Join~
  DeleteDuplicates[Apply[Join, (#[[3, 2]] /. C[1] -> Range[0, #[[2, 5]]] &) /@ a[[-4 ;; -1]] ]]
```

Next, we use Gauss-Legendre points in each sub-interval. The most (computer) efficient way might be to use

```
NIntegrate`GaussKronrodRuleData[points,precision]
```

as used in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html#381359375) on integration rules and then rescale the points according to the sub-intervals. However, for brevity and convenience, we will use `GaussianQuadratureWeights` from the NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis` package:

```
Needs["NumericalDifferentialEquationAnalysis`"]

points = (GaussianQuadratureWeights[21, ##] &) @@@ 
Partition[Sort@zeroes, 2, 1];

pointsf = SortBy[Join @@ points, First];

Total[pointsf[[All, 2]]*g[pointsf[[All, 1]]]]/(6*Pi) - 
1 // AbsoluteTiming (* relative error *)
```

output: `(* {0.151416, 8.65974*10^-13} *)`

One should also consider the time used to obtain the zeroes but if the integral has to be used for a range of frequencies, using Reduce symbolically would be a one time cost.

Comment: Saw your answer now after posting similar one. You could use `v[$MachineEpsilon/2] == 0` instead and this should produce better result. no need to use magic number like `10^(-12)`

Comment: +1. Very interesting and nonstandard.

Comment: @user64494 I might have seen that method applied on stack exchange in the past but I do not remember well. I have used that method in the past and I am still a bit surprised how well it works. Quadrature methods have exponential convergence on analytical functions with a finite radius of convergence. The trapezoidal rule has exponential convergence on periodic functions with a finite radius of convergence and double exponential methods are fairly efficient in handling endpoint singularities. When no reasonably fast exponential convergence is possible, perhaps it is best to use NDSolve.

Answer (score 4):

Stripping "GlobalAdaptive" of the "extras" produces correct results quickly:

```mathematica
AbsoluteTiming[
 res1 =
  NIntegrate[
   Cos[2022*t]*Sin[10050*t]*Sin[10251*t]/Sin[50*t]/Sin[51*t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}, PrecisionGoal -> 6, 
   Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", MinRecursion -> 6, 
     MaxRecursion -> 1000, "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 10^6, 
     "SingularityDepth" -> Infinity, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]
 ]

(* {0.630764, 18.8496} *)

6 Pi - res1

(* 2.63789*10^-11 *)
```

```mathematica
AbsoluteTiming[
 res2 =
  NIntegrate[
   Cos[2022*t]*Sin[10050*t]*Sin[10251*t]/Sin[50*t]/Sin[51*t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}, PrecisionGoal -> 12, WorkingPrecision -> 30, 
   Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", MinRecursion -> 6, 
     MaxRecursion -> 1000, "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 10^6, 
     "SingularityDepth" -> Infinity, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}]
 ]

(* {7.55792, 18.8495559215387594307749777268} *)

6 Pi - res2

(* 8.825728*10^-22 *)
```

---

Let us verify using an alternative method, "LocalAdaptive", and alternative accuracy and precision goals (but still without symbolic pre-processing):

````mathematica
AbsoluteTiming[
 res3 = NIntegrate[
   Cos[2022*t]*Sin[10050*t]*Sin[10251*t]/Sin[50*t]/Sin[51*t], {t, 0, 2*Pi}, AccuracyGoal -> 12, PrecisionGoal -> 12, 
   MaxRecursion -> 10^6, MaxPoints -> 10^8, 
   Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]]

(* {0.877531, 18.8496} *)

6 Pi - res3

(* -4.57681*10^-9 *)

```
````

Comment: +1 for your extremal options.

Comment: @AntonAntonov  I tested the methods proposed so far and after replacing the upper bound 2*Pi by 10*Pi, this method seems to be the fastest and most precise.

Comment: @userrandrand Thanks. You can post another answer with a table that has the timings.

Comment: @AntonAntonov sorry it seems that I just had to increase the number of points rather than bisections in the method provided by Goofy. I wrote an answer with the timings but then deleted it as they are not enlightening other than the case of NDSolve which fails starting at 8*Pi for an unknown reason.

Answer (score 3):

It's kind of a pain, but you can break up the integral yourself.

```
integrand = (Cos[2022*t]*Sin[10050*t]*Sin[10251*t])/(Sin[50*t]*Sin[51*t])
```

To determine where one might break it up, we can plot pieces of the integrand.

```
Plot[integrand, {t, 0, .0005}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
and the end has the same behavior.

Plot[integrand, {t, 2 \[Pi] - .0005, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Those two plots show a substantial chunk of the integral value.

I broke `NIntegrate` up as follows:

First the two sections I plotted,

```
int1 = NIntegrate[integrand, {t, 0, .0005}]
(*5.671497870331018*)

int2 = NIntegrate[integrand, {t, 2 \[Pi] - .0005, 2 \[Pi]}]
(*5.671497870331018*)
```

The next two segments are 1) the end of the first segment to `0.1 Pi` and 2) `1.9 Pi` to the start of the last segment.

```
int3 = NIntegrate[integrand, {t, .0005, .1 \[Pi]}]
(*-0.8981984314029957*)

int4 = NIntegrate[integrand, {t, 1.9 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi] - .0005}]
(*-0.8981984314029957*)
```

and the final integral goes from `0.1 Pi` to `1.9 Pi` in `0.1 Pi` increments.

```
int5 = Total@ Table[NIntegrate[integrand, {t, .1 \[Pi] i, .1 \[Pi] i + .1 \[Pi]}], {i, 1, 18}]
(*9.30295704371735*)
```

Add them all.

```
int = int1 + int2 + int3 + int4 + int5
(*18.84955592150306*)
```

Compare to the known value

```
6 \[Pi] // N
(*18.84955592153876*)
```

Pretty close.  None of the integrations gave me `failed to converge` errors, so this method evidently works, but I have no idea why `NIntegrate` cannot do this automatically.

Comment: +1. Thank you. This is  rather a handwork with help of Mathematica.