# How can I reduce computation time while still obtaining a good approximation for my function?

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, performance-tuning, timing

I am new to any CAS (and Mathematica, for that matter) and new to StackExchange too, so forgive me and correct me on any mistakes.

I have this function:
$J_p=\sum_{m,n=1}^{\infty} \epsilon_{mn}f_{mn}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{J_k^2(\beta)(m\Omega+k\omega)}{1+(m\Omega+k\omega)^2}$ where $\epsilon_{mn}=-\frac{m n}{4\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\epsilon(p_x,p_y)\exp(-i(m p_x+n p_y))\,dp_x dp_y$ and $f_{mn}=-\frac{m n}{4\pi^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\exp(-i(m p_x+n p_y))}{1+\exp(-\epsilon(p_x,p_y))}\,dp_x dp_y$ where again $\epsilon(p_x,p_y)=\sqrt{1+4\cos\left(\frac{p_y}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{p_x\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)+4\cos^2\left(\frac{p_y}{2}\right)}$.

Here is my Mathematica code to evaluate this:

```
Off[NIntegrate::ncvi];
epsilonCoeffsMMA[cl_] := Module[{reComp, imComp},
   reComp[m_, n_] := (-m n)/(4 \[Pi]^2)
      NIntegrate[
      Re[(1 + 4 Cos[py /2] Cos[(px Sqrt[3])/2] + 4 Cos[py/2]^2)^(1/2)
         Exp[-I (m px + n py)]], {px, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {py, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
      Method -> "Trapezoidal", MaxRecursion -> 100];
   imComp[m_, n_] := (-m n)/(4 \[Pi]^2)
      NIntegrate[
      Im[(1 + 4 Cos[py /2] Cos[(px Sqrt[3])/2] + 4 Cos[py/2]^2)^(1/2)
         Exp[-I (m px + n py)]], {px, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {py, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
      Method -> "Trapezoidal", MaxRecursion -> 100];
   emnMatrix = Table[0, {m, 1, cl}, {n, 1, cl}];
   Do[emnMatrix[[m, n]] = reComp[m, n] + I imComp[m, n], {m, 1, 
     cl}, {n, 1, cl}];
   ];
boltzECoeffsMMA[cl_] := Module[{reComp, imComp},
reComp[m_, n_] := (-m n)/(4 \[Pi]^2)
      NIntegrate[
      Re[Exp[-I (m px + n py)]/(1 + 
          Exp[-(1 + 4 Cos[py /2] Cos[(px Sqrt[3])/2] + 
              4 Cos[py/2]^2)^(1/2)])], {px, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {py, 0, 
       2 \[Pi]}, Method -> "Trapezoidal", MaxRecursion -> 100];
   imComp[m_, n_] := (-m n)/(4 \[Pi]^2)
      NIntegrate[
      Im[(1 + 4 Cos[py /2] Cos[(px Sqrt[3])/2] + 4 Cos[py/2]^2)^(1/2)
         Exp[-I (m px + n py)]], {px, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {py, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
      Method -> "Trapezoidal", MaxRecursion -> 100];
   fmnMatrix = Table[0, {m, 1, cl}, {n, 1, cl}];
   Do[fmnMatrix[[m, n]] = reComp[m, n] + I imComp[m, n], {m, 1, 
     cl}, {n, 1, cl}];
   ];
jPMMA[coeffLim_, kernLim_] := Module[
  {cl = coeffLim, kl = kernLim, px, py},
  epsilonCoeffsMMA[cl]; boltzECoeffsMMA[cl];
  coeffMatrix = emnMatrix fmnMatrix;
  sumMatrix = 
   Table[Sum[(
     BesselJ[k, \[Beta]]^2 (m \[CapitalOmega] + k \[Omega]))/(
     1 + (m \[CapitalOmega] + k \[Omega])^2), {k, -kl, kl}], {m, 1, 
     cl}, {n, 1, cl}];
  jParaMMA = Total[coeffMatrix sumMatrix, 2];
  ];
```

This generates a function `jParaMMA` which I can `Plot` after I have made the call `jPMMA[a,b]` for some integers; `a` and `b`. For example

```
jPMMA[10, 10];
Plot[Evaluate@
Re[jParaMMA /. {\[Beta] ->2, \[Omega] -> {0, 2, 4, 6, 8}}], {\[CapitalOmega], 0, 20}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Plot of the function jParaMMA for [Beta]->2 and [Omega] -> {0, 2, 4, 6, 8}]

for which

```
First[Timing[jPMMA[10, 10]]]
```

gives

```
115.437500
```

My question is: How can I obtain similar results, possibly with more terms (i.e. from running `jPMMA[50, 60]`, say.) in a shorter time,? Thank you.

PS: I used the `Off[NIntegrate::ncvi]` because I do not know how to eliminate it from my numerical integration and I'd be glad to obtain some help for that too. Also, I used the `Trapezoidal` method because I noticed it gave a faster approximation even when coupled with `MaxRecursion -> 100`. I have tried with the Cuba library implementation in both Mathematica and Maple, which I was led to by [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26623/integration-strategies-for-oscillatory-multidimensional-function/26678#26678), and the approximations are appreciably close.

Comment: Since your $\epsilon_{mn}$ matrix is basically just the positive-frequency portion of the fast Fourier transform of the $\epsilon$ function, I feel like the use of `NIntegrate` might actually not even be necessary, and a much faster method may be available. I'll see what I can do and post an answer in a few hours if I can figure it out.

Comment: Question: Is your notation $\int_0^{2\pi}dp_xdp_y$ a shorthand for double integral $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}dp_xdp_y$ over a square region?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus; yes, that is a double integral, as you may have figured. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I think I can speed this up by a huge factor. I'll post in a while.

Comment: One other question: your $\epsilon$ and $f$ arrays look sort of like Fourier coefficients, but your function $\epsilon(p_x,p_y)$ is not periodic on the $[0,2\pi]\times[0,2\pi]$ interval, so they're technically not really Fourier coefficients. Is that correct?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus; you're right. The function $\epsilon(p_x,p_y)$ is actually periodic on the $[-2\pi,2\pi]^2$ (or $[0,4\pi]^2$) interval. $\epsilon_{m n}$ and $f_{m n}$ are Fourier coefficients.

Comment: Ugh, this is so strange. The $\epsilon$ function is quite smooth, but getting the FFT coefficients to be accurate is surprisingly difficult, with $5000\times 5000$ sampling grid for less than 1% error...

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus; sorry, I made a mistake. The function $\epsilon(p_x,p_y)$ is periodic on the $[-2\pi/\sqrt{3},2\pi/\sqrt{3}]\times[-2\pi,2\pi]$ (or $[0,4\pi/\sqrt{3}]\times[0,4\pi]$) interval. I might have to ask my professor the reason for the integration limits not coinciding with the periodicity of the function. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hmm, I found the reason why the FFT computation is so bad. According to http://www.aip.de/groups/soe/local/numres/bookcpdf/c13-9.pdf (from "Numerical Recipes in C"), it is tempting but very often **massively inaccurate** from a numerical perspective to compute Fourier coefficients using the FFT! Quoting from the book, "It is a sobering exercise to implement equation (13.9.6) for an integral that can be done
analytically, and to see just how bad it is. We recommend that you try it." They then go on to provide a higher-order interpolation scheme. I'll give it a shot when I have time.

Answer (score 3):

Timing under 20 seconds on my computer now.
Ok, your original program took about 60 seconds on my computer meaning that my computer is faster.

The dramatical gain of time is due to halfing the `MaxRecursion` option value.
The plot still shows no visible difference.

I replaced Pi-Symbol by Pi for increasing readability in forum.
I tested some scenarios, and replaced your initialization with 0 for the matrix and made `px`, `py` local, here you can't win seconds, but shortens progam. Here I tested also with `ClearSystemCache` and `AbsoluteTiming`

your Timing result on my computer as image

[image: optimization1]

After the changes mentioned the result is:

[image: optimization2]

Here my changes:

```
Clear@"`*";
Off[NIntegrate::ncvi];
maxRecursion = 50;
epsilonCoeffsMMA[cl_] := 
  Module[{reComp, imComp, px, py}, 
   reComp[m_, 
     n_] := (-m n)/(4 Pi^2) NIntegrate[
      Re[(1 + 4 Cos[py/2] Cos[(px Sqrt[3])/2] + 4 Cos[py/2]^2)^(1/
           2) Exp[-I (m px + n py)]], {px, 0, 2 Pi}, {py, 0, 2 Pi}, 
      Method -> "Trapezoidal", MaxRecursion -> maxRecursion];
   imComp[m_, 
     n_] := (-m n)/(4 Pi^2) NIntegrate[
      Im[(1 + 4 Cos[py/2] Cos[(px Sqrt[3])/2] + 4 Cos[py/2]^2)^(1/
           2) Exp[-I (m *px + n*py)]], {px, 0, 2 Pi}, {py, 0, 2 Pi}, 
      Method -> "Trapezoidal", MaxRecursion -> maxRecursion];
   emnMatrix = 
    Table[reComp[m, n] + I imComp[m, n], {m, 1, cl}, {n, 1, cl}]];
boltzECoeffsMMA[cl_] := 
  Module[{reComp, imComp, px, py}, 
   reComp[m_, 
     n_] := (-m n)/(4 Pi^2) NIntegrate[
      Re[Exp[-I (m *px + n * py)]/(1 + 
          Exp[-(1 + 4 Cos[py/2] Cos[(px Sqrt[3])/2] + 
               4 Cos[py/2]^2)^(1/2)])], {px, 0, 2 Pi}, {py, 0, 2 Pi}, 
      Method -> "Trapezoidal", MaxRecursion -> maxRecursion];
   imComp[m_, 
     n_] := (-m n)/(4 Pi^2) NIntegrate[
      Im[(1 + 4 Cos[py/2] Cos[(px Sqrt[3])/2] + 4 Cos[py/2]^2)^(1/
           2) Exp[-I (m*px + n*py)]], {px, 0, 2 Pi}, {py, 0, 2 Pi}, 
      Method -> "Trapezoidal", MaxRecursion -> maxRecursion];
   fmnMatrix = 
    Table[reComp[m, n] + I imComp[m, n], {m, 1, cl}, {n, 1, cl}]];
jPMMA[coeffLim_, kernLim_] := 
  Module[{cl = coeffLim, kl = kernLim}, epsilonCoeffsMMA[cl]; 
   boltzECoeffsMMA[cl];
   coeffMatrix = emnMatrix * fmnMatrix;
   sumMatrix = 
    Table[Sum[(BesselJ[k, β]^2 (m Ω + 
           k ω))/(1 + (m Ω + 
            k ω)^2), {k, -kl, kl}], {m, 1, cl}, {n, 1, cl}];
   jParaMMA = Total[coeffMatrix * sumMatrix, 2];];
```

So it's up to you, if tuning `MaxRecursion` is worth a compromise.
Pick what you like, just some ideas...